# Why do VisualVM float instances not seem to include floats inside other classes?

Tags: java, debugging, class, instance, visualvm

I am looking at a java virtual machine that's running an application. VisualVM says that java.lang.Float only has 102 instances.

Yet, there is also a class called Vector3 which has 80.000 instances. All these instances appear to have 3 float fields.

So, there should be *at least* 80.000 * 3 float instances right? Why not?

**Update:**
This lead me to a follow up question, posted here: [VisualVM OQL: how to search for primitive float values rather than actual Float instances?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021988/visualvm-oql-how-to-search-for-primitive-float-values-rather-than-actual-float-i)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`float` is a primitive value.

`java.lang.Float` is an object used to wrap up ('[box](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberclasses.html)') a float value into a referencable object.

A float field is not an instance of the boxed object. It's a primitive value.

It doesn't matter how many primitive fields you have - as they are not objects, they won't be counted in the object instance counts.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot. However, this leads me to the question:  how do I search for values of primitive values in VisualVM ?

Comment: I posted my follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5021988/visualvm-oql-how-to-search-for-primitive-float-values-rather-than-actual-float-i

Answer (score 1):

To be precise, you have approximately 80.000 * 3 *references* to `Float` instances, but you have no guarantee that they are not referencing the same `Float` instances. Basically you have 102 `Float` instances, but each of them (or maybe just few) are referenced several times in different places.

`Float` instances, like all other primitive wrappers, are immutable, so there is nothing wrong with this.

Comment: It seems very hard to believe that those 80.000 values have so many equal ones. This must be the case though... thanks. In fact, I am very sure that the app I am monitoring cannot suffice with only 120 different float values.. how weird.

Comment: @Tom, you can create an small app with something like this: `for( int i =  0 ; i < 121 ; i++ ) { list.add( new Float( i ) ); }` and confirm, you have +120 different objects.

Comment: The difference is that I was expecting Float to include primitive float values.