# VisualVM OQL: how to search for primitive float values rather than actual Float instances?

Tags: java, primitive, visualvm, oql

I am wondering how one can search for all primitive float values that match a certain number.

When doing something like:

```
select n from java.lang.Float n where n.value == 1.00
```

Only the Float class instances are being found. The application I am exploring is using different wrappers than just Float (eg. Vectors) that use primitive float values as fields for which I need to search.

How would I  accomplish this?

The following returns a "float is not found error":

```
select n from float n where n.value == 1.00
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A primitive value exists only as a field in the structure it's a part of (or directly on the stack).  Because it isn't an object, it can't be referenced.  Try something like the following:

```
select v from Vector v where v.x == 1.0 || v.y == 1.0 || v.z == 1.0
```

---

If you want to examine all float fields in all objects, it **should** be possible to use OQL's reflection capabilities to do so, using something like the following:

```
select filter(heap.objects(), function(it) {
  var cls = classof(it);
  while (cls) {
    for (var i = 0; i < cls.fields.length; i++) {
      var field = cls.fields[i];
      if (field.signature == 'F' && it[field.name] == 0.0)
        return true;
      }
    cls = cls.superclass;
  }
  return false;
})
```

However, while this works correctly using jhat, it doesn't work in my version of VisualVM (1.6.0_22), because cls.fields seems to improperly return a list of static fields rather than instance fields.

It's also very slow, taking 10 seconds to search a 1MB heap dump.  It's probably possible to optimize the code and also speed things up by only searching a limited set of classes.

Comment: the problem here is that I do not know what classes use it. Is there no way to search through ALL classes and ALL fields that are primitive floats?

Comment: that approach is exactly what I need. Unfortunately I cannot make it work though, I think your code has some problems. I am trying to solve it but no luck so far. Will accept your answer when I get it working. Why do you get the class of the object? That is probably why it only returns static fields (objects have non-static fields).